# Swift - Crashing on tableView.deleteRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

**How can I fix this crashing when trying to remove a cell from a tableview?**

Debugger shows the error on that line: *tableView.deleteRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)*

With this message: 
*2018-02-05 23:13:42.355696-0800 Invoice[66511:19435120] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/UITableView.m:2011*

Data is loaded from a server that returns a json. Adding, loading and updating work fine.

```
@IBAction func unwindToClients(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? ClientViewController,
        let client = sourceViewController.client,
        let wasDeleted = sourceViewController.wasDeleted {

        if(wasDeleted) {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                print("Delteted")
                tableArray.remove(at: selectedIndexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }

        }
        else {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                // Update an existing client.
                tableArray[selectedIndexPath.row] = client
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
            else {
                // Add a client.
                tableArray.append(client)

            }
        }

        prepareData()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Function prepareData() orders the array and get indexes (A,B,C...)

```
//sorts and makes the index
func prepareData() {
    let firstLetters = self.tableArray.map { $0.nameFirstLetter }
    let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

    self.sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
    self.sections = self.sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
        return self.tableArray
            .filter { $0.nameFirstLetter == firstLetter }
            .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might dispatch `deleteRows(at` and `reloadRows(at` also to the main thread. Further I would use `insertRows` after the append line and remove the `reloadData()` block.

Comment: I tried DispatchQueue.main.async {...., still crashing. Same with adding.

Comment: I just noticed that the crash happens on the last item in a section. If i have 3 cells in a section and delete any 2.... the last one crashes on delete. Mayve something related to empty section?

Answer (score 0):

Perform delete operation in between `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`.

For Example :

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: `beginUpdates / endUpdates` has no effect at all for a single operation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update your dataSource while using `deleteRows` and `insertRows`